# C#: Why I can only connect to my ip address but the other ip address, getting error (WMI)

Tags: c#, networking

I'm trying to connect to other network using my pc but im getting error

> (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)')

However, It's only working if I connect to my pc itself. Is there any approach aside from this process because I cant even figure what's the error if it's like firewall,my codes or my anti-virus etc.

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // remote computer.
    ManagementScope scope =
        new ManagementScope(
        "\\\\172.20.1.50\\root\\cimv2");
    scope.Connect();


    //Query system for Operating System information
    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
        // Display the remote computer information


        MessageBox.Show(m["csname"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read through this

[Connecting to WMI Remotely with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703458(v=vs.85).aspx)

1. Create a `ManagementScope` object, using the name of the computer and the WMI path, and connect to your target with a call to `ManagementScope.Connect()`.
2. If you connect to a remote computer in a different domain or using a different user name and password, then you must use a [`ConnectionOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) object in the call to the `ManagementScope`.

> The `ConnectionOptions` contains properties for describing the
> Authentication, Impersonation, username, password, and other
> connection options.

**Example**

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

// options takes more arguments, you need to read up on what you want

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\FullComputerName\\root\\cimv2", options);
scope.Connect();

ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ObjectGetOptions o = new ObjectGetOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass(scope, path, o);
...
```

Generally speaking, it is recommended that you set your Impersonation level to Impersonate unless explicitly needed otherwise.

Assuming you have the correct credentials, I think this will turn out to be a firewall issue, or a windows setting on the remote computer.

I'd apply the following firewall rules first and work backwards. Or for a test completely disable firewalls on the target machine

- COM+ Network Access (DCOM-In)
- Remote Event Log Management (NP-In)
- Remote Event Log Management (RPC)
- Remote Event Log Management (RPC-EPMAP)
- Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)
- Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)
- Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)

---

**Additional reading**

[Connecting to WMI Remotely with C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703458(v=vs.85).aspx)

[ManagementScope Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ConnectionOptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.connectionoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ObjectGetOptions Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.objectgetoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ManagementPath Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ManagementClass Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Disclaimer** : You will have to read about these topics and work out what you need in your situation.

Comment: @DevGeorge this seems unlikely. i mean these apis are designed for this

Comment: sir. can i ask about the connection open?? what kind of username and password value declared to the string? i dont understand ConnectionOptions Options = new ConnectionOptions(); 
//String Domain = "mydomain"; 
String Domain = ""; 
//Options.Username = "administrator"; 
//Options.Password = "mypassword";